# Fill Nulls in Pandas Column with Not Nulls in Same Column Based on Range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a date field that is mostly null. However, in between these nulls I have some cells filled in with the correct value (see cells 755 and 758 below).

How could I fill in the missing values in between the cells with existing values, with the first existing value below it?

In other words, in the snippet below cells 753 and 754 should be the same as 755. Cells 756 and 757 should be the same as 758.

I have many rows, and I don't always have only 2 nulls in between. Is there a way to do this efficiently in pandas or python?

```
data.iloc[753:760]

753          NaT
754          NaT
755   2008-05-05
756          NaT
757          NaT
758   2008-05-09
759          NaT
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: You can use `data.fillna(method='bfill')`

Comment: Thanks so much! I had no idea that was there

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Gaurav Taneja, the way to go is simply:

```
data.fillna(method='bfill')
```